# Inject method to codebehind from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, linq, namespaces, using-statement

I have an aspx page belonging to a legacy application. Since I cannot access to the relative aspx.cs file, I have to inject some needed logic through the aspx file, like:

```
<%
  using (myNamespace.myLinqContext cnt = new myNamespace.myLinqContext())
        {
         var warningText = (from c in cnt.Table_Customer
                            where c.ID.Equals(CustomerId)
                            select c).First();
        }       
%>
```

However I would get an exception since the namespace System.Linq is not imported in the codebehind file.

**How could I import/use it in this context, so that I could execute the Linq query from the aspx page?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it helps, but try to import Linq namespace directly in the aspx.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

Also the page classes is partial, so maybe you can move your logic somewhere where you can ge access to the code.

Comment: I think it does not work perfectly. I get an exception at runtime in the asox field saying thaat ")" is missing where the Linq query starts. The query howvere is correct since I compiled and tested it  on codebehind before.

Comment: try to use extensions: `cnt.Table_Customer.Where(c => c.ID == CustomerId).First()`

Comment: Also in this case I get an exception on the ">" character. I decided to develop a web service as suggested by Neelam. However +1 for the import hint!